# How to merge DataFrames only if one column meets a certain condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have a dataframe 'df_main':

```
ID   Type
1    Car
1    Truck
2    Truck
```

And another dataframe 'truck_data':

```
Truck_ID         Data
1          TruckData1
2          TruckData2
```

Merging these two gives the dataframe:

```
   ID   Type  Truck_ID        Data
0   1    Car         1  TruckData1
1   1  Truck         1  TruckData1
2   2  Truck         2  TruckData2
```

How can I modify the merge statement to only merge in the rows from truck_data that match on ID if and only if the Type == 'Truck'?

Desired output:

```
   ID   Type  Truck_ID        Data
0   1    Car         1  
1   1  Truck         1  TruckData1
2   2  Truck         2  TruckData2
```

Current code:

```
df_main = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ID', 'Type'], data=[[1, 'Car'], [1, 'Truck'], [2, 'Truck']])
truck_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Truck_ID', 'Data'], data=[[1, 'TruckData1'], [2, 'TruckData2']])
df_main = df_main.merge(truck_df, left_on='ID', right_on='Truck_ID', how='left')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Filter the required rows` from df1 / `perform merge` /`concat` the unfiltered rows.

```
m = df_main.Type.eq('Truck')
merged_df = pd.concat([df_main.loc[~m], df_main.loc[m].merge(truck_df, left_on='ID', right_on='Truck_ID')]
```

OUTPUT:

```
   ID   Type        Data
0   1    Car         NaN
0   1  Truck  TruckData1
1   2  Truck  TruckData2
```

Comment: thanks, i ended up editing it slightly to meet the actual requirements of the question:

merged_df = pd.concat([df_main.loc[~m], df_main.loc[m].merge(truck_df, left_on='ID', right_on='Truck_ID')])

Answer (score 3):

I'd do it like this:

```
df_main.merge(truck_df.assign(Type='Truck'), on=['ID', 'Type'], how='left')
```

Output:

```
   ID   Type        Data
0   1    Car         NaN
1   1  Truck  TruckData1
2   2  Truck  TruckData2
```

Details:

`assign` a temporary column to truck_df named 'Type' and merge on both 'ID' an 'Type' with `how='left'`

Comment: sorry, i forgot to edit my question. the truck_data's ID field is actually called 'Truck_ID'. how can i modify the code above to handle this?